# Gaussian distribution proof of large Poisson data

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, chi-squared

I am trying to proof that large poisson data follows gaussian distribution using Goodness–of–fit tests. I am stuck at calculating the degree of freedom.

My question is, since the data are from poisson distribution then I calculated the standard deviation as the square root of the mean. and for the normal distribution I need both mean and standard deviation. but what is the correct value for the degree of freedom here?

I know that for poisson distribution its k-2 (since we estimate the mean) and k is the data points. and for normal distribution  its k-3 (since we estimate the mean and the standard deviation). But in my case the standard deviation comes from poisson data and its dependent on the mean. What is the correct degree of freedom in this case, k-2 or k-3 ?

Thanks

Comment: (a) You can't **prove** anything with any kind of goodness-of-fit test.  (a) What GOF test do you have in mind? (b) What do you mean by 'large Poisson data'? Large sample, large mean, or both? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A Chi-Squared Goodness-of-Fit Test: Are Poisson Data Nearly Normal?

**Poisson Data.** Suppose you have $n = 1000$ observations from
$\mathsf{POIS}(\lambda=100).$ Then the resulting
data should be approximately distributed as
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=10).$

```
set.seed(123)
x = rpois(1000, 100)
summary(x); sd(x)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  66.0    93.0    99.5    99.5   106.0   130.0 
[1] 9.906065
```

The sample mean is about 100 and the sample SD is about 10. So the mean and SD are nearly correct. What about the normal shape?

```
hist(x, br=seq(59.5, 139.5, by=10), ylim=c(0,400), labels=T)
```

[image]

**Chi-squared GOF test.** Judging by eye, the histogram seems to have an approximately normal shape. Let's try a chi-squared GOF test to see if the approximation is "good".

*Observed Poisson counts:* We
use six intervals taken from the histogram: `<79.5`, `79.5 to 89,5`, ...
`109.5 to 119.5`, and `>119.5`. These intervals have
observed frequencies: 24, 132, 344, 345, 133, and 22, respectively.

```
obs = c(24, 132, 344, 345, 133, 22)
```

Now I will use R to go through the steps of the
chi-squared goodness-of-fit test. You should follow
through the computations here and match them with
examples and formulas in your text.

Your null hypothesis is that data fit $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=10).$ So we need to get probabilities for each of the six intervals according to this distribution. One can get these in R, but you should
show how to use printed normal tables to get them.

```
prob = round(diff(pnorm(c(0, seq(79.5, 119.5, by=10), 200), 100, 10)),4)
prob
[1] 0.0202 0.1267 0.3332 0.3489 0.1455 0.0256
```

*Expected counts based on null hypothesis:* Then under the null hypothesis of a normal fit, the expected counts are as shown below. [In order for
the so-called 'chi-squared statistic' to have approximately a chi-squared distribution, all expected counts should exceed 5. That's why I didn't try to use
eight histogram intervals instead of six.]

```
exp = 1000*prob;  exp
[1]  20.2 126.7 333.2 348.9 145.5  25.6
```

*Chi-squared statistic:* Then the chi-squared statistic is 2.91. (You should look
for this formula in your text.)

```
sum((obs-exp)^2/exp)
[1]  2.910344
```

*Degrees of freedom:* With $k = 6$ intervals we have $\nu = k-1 = 5$ degrees
of freedom. (We obtained the normal mean $\mu = 100$ and
standard deviation $\sigma = 10$ by a theoretical argument, not by estimation from data, so there is no
'penalty' for estimation in finding the degrees of freedom.)

*Critical value for test at 5% level:* The critical value for a test at the 5% level is
$c = 11.071$ from R or from printed tables of chi-squared distributions.

*Conclusion from test:* Because the chi-squared statistic is smaller than $c,$ we cannot reject the null hypothesis that the Poisson data (except for their
discrete integer values) are consistent with a normal distribution.

```
qchisq(.95, 5)
[1] 11.0705
```

The figure below shows the density function of
the chi-squared distribution with degrees of
freedom $\nu = 5.$ The solid vertical line
shows the observed value of the chi-squared GOF
statistic and the dotted vertical line shows
the critical value for a test at the 5% level.

[image]

***Note:*** Of course, a Poisson distribution (even with large $\lambda)$ is not exactly normal. Any Poisson distribution is discrete and right-skewed, whereas a normal distribution is continuous and symmetrical. For larger sizes $n$ of the Poisson
sample, the GOF test becomes more likely to detect small
differences between the Poisson counts and a normal
distribution.

If you do you own example, you might
want to use $n = 500$ observations, rather than
my $n = 1000.$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations!! Its exactly the situation I have. The only difference I have is that the data are experimental not theoretical so the degree of freedom will be affected by the mean and sigma. I also have larger observations. n is around 2000 and the mean is very small.

Comment: If the Poisson mean is very small, then a normal fit may be problematic. The Poisson mean and variance are the same, so you'd really be estimating only one parameter.